# How to use sed to replace a word in a file with control characters

Tags: linux, sed

How to replace this word in a file globally which has control characters. how can i do that ? I have tried the below with no success.

```
Replace "^Aabc_def_a^B" with "^Adef_a^B" globally
```

Tried the below

```
sed -i 's/^Aabc_def_a^B/^Adef_a^B/g' file.txt 

sed -i 's/\^Aabc_def_a\^B/\^Adef_a\^B/g'file.txt

sed 's/x01abc_def_ax02/x01def_ax02/g'
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, could you edit it to improve clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work for me:

```
$ echo -n "^Aword^B" | sed 's/^Aword^B/^Alexical unit^B/' | hexdump -C
00000000  01 6c 65 78 69 63 61 6c  20 75 6e 69 74 02 0a     |.lexical unit..|
0000000f
```

`01` represents `^A`; `02` represents `^B`.

Bear in mind that I used literal control characters, not a caret (`^`) followed by the `A` or `B`.  To enter them when crafting your `sed` command, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> followed by the control character to insert it literally rather than having `readline` parse it as input.

In other words, to insert a `^A`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, and you will see `^A` displayed as your input.  If you try to arrow past this, you will observe your cursor always treating this as a single unit even though it is comprised of two characters on your screen.

Answer (score 1):

In GNU sed, `\xHH` works:

```
$ printf '\001foo\002\n' | sed 's/\x01foo\x02/\x01bar\x02/g' | od -c
0000000 001   b   a   r 002  \n
```

If you don't have GNU sed, but have Bash, you can use the `$''` quoting to generate the control characters in the shell:

```
$ printf '\001foo\002\n' | sed $'s/\x01foo\x02/\x01bar\x02/g' | od -c
0000000  001   b   a   r 002  \n
```

If you have neither, there's always Perl which also understands `\xHH`:

```
$ printf '\001foo\002\n' | perl -pe 's/\x01foo\x02/\x01bar\x02/g' | od -c
0000000  001   b   a   r 002  \n
```

Of course you can do the same with `-i`.